# bin: command not found for magick

Tags: imagemagick, robotframework

I am trying to get magick for robot framework.

I followed the instructions from this detailed guide

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/09/robot-framework-compare-images-screenshots/

I have already navigated into the bin folder --> cd /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-46/bin

When i issue the command --> bin ./magick -version

I received an error -bash: bin: command not found

Not too sure what it means cause im new to MAC OS and this magick tool as well.

Comment: bin is your working directory. So you are already there. Just use `./magick -version` or just `magick -versioin`. But see Mark Setchell's more complete answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ugh! **homebrew** generally installs packages under:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/PACKAGENAME/VERSION
```

but it also creates symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin`. You can see these with:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/magick
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  41 17 May 10:49 /usr/local/bin/magick -> ../Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-44/bin/magick
```

So, all you need to do is ensure that your `PATH` contains `/usr/local/bin` like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

and pretty much everything you install with **homebrew** will work:

```
magick -version
```

**Sample Output**

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-44 Q16 x86_64 2019-05-11 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(3.1) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png tiff webp xml zlib
```

---

If you find that command works, you can run it in your bash profile in `$HOME/.profile` every time you log in.